# Convert a string of Dictionaries to a list of dictionaries

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a string that contains a number of dictionaries (1 to n), I want to change it to a list of dictionarier, if it has more than one dictionary, it works fine:

```
str_dic = '{"Name": "banana", "Color": "yellow", "Count": "three"}, {"Name": "apple", "Color": "red", "Count": "five"}'
lst = list(eval(str_dic))
print(type(lst))
print(lst)

>>> <class 'list'>
>>> [{'Name': 'banana', 'Color': 'yellow', 'Count': 'three'}, {'Name': 'apple', 'Color': 'red', 'Count': 'five'}]
```

but when the string contains only one dictionary, it returns only the keys and does not return the values.

```
str_dic = '{"Name": "banana", "Color": "yellow", "Count": "three"}'
lst = list(eval(str_dic))
print(type(lst))
print(lst)

>>> <class 'list'>
>>> ['Name', 'Color', 'Count']
```

Comment: Try replacing `list(eval(str_dic))` with just `eval(str_dic)` in your last example. `eval(str_dic)` becomes a dictionary; trying to convert a dictionary to a list like that only keeps the keys and discards the values.

Comment: With a comma it becomes a tuple instead of a single dict. Why do you have dict strings in this… weird… format to begin with? You should never have to `eval` data, you should have it in a safe and unambiguously parsable format, like a JSON list.

Answer (score 2):

Appending square brackets to the string before eval would solve this:

```
str_dic = '[{"Name": "banana", "Color": "yellow", "Count": "three"}, {"Name": "apple", "Color": "red", "Count": "five"}]'
lst = eval(str_dic)
print(lst)

str_dic = '[{"Name": "banana", "Color": "yellow", "Count": "three"}]'
lst = eval(str_dic)
print(lst)
```

Output:

```
[{'Name': 'banana', 'Color': 'yellow', 'Count': 'three'}]
[{'Name': 'banana', 'Color': 'yellow', 'Count': 'three'}, {'Name': 'apple', 'Color': 'red', 'Count': 'five'}]
```

Comment: Simple and efficient. However be careful not to call `eval` on a non-safe user-inputted string.

Comment: Use `json.loads()` instead of `eval()`.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are working with `JSON` data, you will need to use Python's built-in module `json`. A quick read of the comments will explain the code.

```
import json

str_dic = '...'
str_dic_list = str_dic.split('}, ')   # Split string dictionaries into list (see Note)
dic_list = []                         # Initialize an empty list for storing dictionaries

for dic in str_dic_list:              # Iterate through the list of string dictionaries
    temp_dic = dic.rstrip('}') + '}'  # Adds trailing "}" at the end of string dictionary (see Note)
    d = json.loads(temp_dic)          # Convert string dictionary (JSON) into dictionary
    dic_list.append(d)                # Append the converted dictionary in the list
```

**Note:**

Here, we use `str_dic.split('}, ')` since using `str_dic.split(', ')` will split each entry within the dictionary rather that splitting the dictionaries itself. For example, it might result in `{'Name': 'banana'` rather than `{'Name': 'banana', 'Color': 'yellow', 'Count': 'three'}`. Well, not exactly. We lose the `}` at the end of each result, so we get something like `{'Name': 'banana', 'Color': 'yellow', 'Count': 'three'` (notice the missing `}`). So, in order to compensate that, we will concatenate the curly brace at the end: `dic + '}'`. But this might result in problem for the last string dictionary as it will retain the curly brace since the splitting does not happen at that point. So, we make sure to strip the end for curly brace and then concatenate it, thus, `dic.rstrip('}') + '}'`.

#### Output

---

```
[{'Name': 'banana', 'Color': 'yellow', 'Count': 'three'}, {'Name': 'apple', 'Color': 'red', 'Count': 'five'}]
```

Comment: It does not seem to work properly and gives an error.

Comment: @Meysam I have updated the code with the required explanation...